I deleted my /etc/alternatives/ by accident
I'm on ubuntu 22.04. I was there removing the files related to libcudnn. However, I thought i was CDing inside, but an enter later, I realized that I was on sudo rm -rfing there. So, I ended up deleting the entire folder. Now, I'm wondering if can I still work on ubuntu like nothing happened? Or should i reinstall it? How important are those alternative links?
And as an alternative solution, (no puns intended) can I just ignore it if i start working in virtual envs?

As a side note, you could map rm to trash-put to avoid accidental deletions in the future. If you choose so, you had to do it for each user (and root).

Virtual envs are a thing for Python only, but /etc/alternatives/ is for anything your system might have had two or more parallel implementations for. /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/ has a metadata file for everything that's using /etc/alternatives/, so you can run ls /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/ to see a list of things that may no longer work as well as before.
I have not tested this personally, but the update-alternatives man page suggests you might be able to fix it by first ensuring the /etc/alternatives/ directory exists and has proper permissions, then reconfiguring all alternatives to their default settings:
sudo install -d -m 755 -o root -g root /etc/alternatives
yes '' | sudo update-alternatives --force --all

After that, all of /etc/alternatives/ should be back to as they would be just after installing the OS and any packages you added.
If you find some of these defaults are not what you were accustomed to using, you can use sudo update-alternatives --config <any name from /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/> to reconfigure it to match your preferences.
